# Store Video on sqlite database or SdCard - Android

Tags: android

In my app i have captured video for each question. After that i've uploaded to the server.

I've used database in my app.

My question is, `where can i keep the videos` ?

user can logout and again log in. that time we keep the captured videos.

Can i store the video in database as blob or can i use store video on sdcard.?

```
if i store the videos on sd card, some time user can remove sd card or delete the videos.

if i plan to store the videos on sqlite, i'm afraid for memory. is it enough for memory?
```

Comment: store the video in sdcard and store the path of the video in database

Comment: Man! SQLite Database may also be cleaned...

Comment: Also better way to store in sdcard in hidden folder so user cant access it directly. you can create hidden folder with `.` prefix before folder name like `.MyVideos`.

Comment: if suppose user delete or remove the sd card? what should i do. we can check the path is exist or not. again need to capture ?

Comment: yes, you can check file exist or not with `file.exist()` where `File file = new File("your file path on sdcard")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store blobs of 500KB in your database. Store path in your database  If you use MODE_PRIVATE, they will not be accessible by other processes.

for more about MODE_PRIVATE, read below thead: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit of 1MB on single items or columns in a SQLite database on Android. Most of your videos are going to be much larger then that.

Save the data as a file then save the file name in the database.

Comment: limit 1 mb on single items means, each vedio size is less than 1 mb?

Comment: there are 20 videos each video have less than 1mb . totllay less than 20 mb .  at that time can we add it on sqlite?. just for know to the information.

Comment: If the video is less then 1 MB, then yes you could put it in the DB, but there are other problems as well because sqlite blobs are slow.  You are just much better to put the stuff on the sdcard because putting 20MB in an sqlite means that 20MB must stay on the phone memory.  Putting it on the SDCard is better because the phone usually has much more memory there.